# "A long time ago" and "far, far away" relative to what?

Tags: star-wars

We all know that the Star Wars movies take place "A long time ago, in a galaxy far far away".  But relative to *what*?

The obvious answer is that it's relative to 20th-century Earth (21st for episodes 2 and 3).

But how plausible is it that both phrases might be relative to the place and time of some hidden narrator rather than the modern audience?

If the story is being told by someone in the distant future of the Star Wars universe (and George Lucas is re-telling that story), that opens the possibility that the humans we see are actually our distant descendants.  For example, the events of the movies might take place 10,000 years in our future, after Earth humans have colonized other galaxies, and the story is being told by someone living, say, 10,000 years after that.

Are there any canonical sources and/or statements by George Lucas that clearly define what "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away" actually means?

(My own thought is that placing the story in the distant past gives a more mythic feel.)

Comment: I would assume this is to the viewers context, attempting to warp it such as this seems to render the entire point of it moot.

Comment: Who says that a species can't be developed on two planets independent of each other..

Comment: @SachinShekhar: The odds against another species independently evolving to resemble humans as closely as the "humans" in Star Wars do are beyond astronomical.

Comment: @KeithThompson - Convergent evolution

Comment: @DVK: Giving it a name doesn't make it any more likely. All species on Earth share common ancestry, and there are no examples of such close convergence.

Comment: @KeithThompson - it's not a "name". It's an evolutionary  biology term. Feel free to google it. Or just Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_examples_of_convergent_evolution

Comment: @DVK: Sorry, I was unclear. I'm familiar with the term and the concept. All the known examples are among organisms that share common ancestry; we're talking about independent species in separate galaxies. I stand by my statement about the unlikelihood of the convergence we see in the movies (but I'm willing to accept it as artistic license).

Comment: This is simply a sci-fi version of "Once upon a time."

Comment: @KeithThompson I can't believe nobody's said this yet - "Never tell me the odds!". That covered, if you assume that the universe is infinite and also recognize that there are a finite number of quantum states that any volume of space in that universe can assume, then it is not only likely but flat-out inevitable that there is another human race out there somewhere - even one that has an identical genome and lives on an identical Earth in a solar system and galaxy identical to ours.

Comment: @KeithThompson You may be interested in [this Numberphile video](http://www.numberphile.com/videos/googolplex.html) and a [related discussion](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22390/would-one-actually-find-their-doppleganger-in-a-googolplex-universe/152743#152743) on [Physics.SE]. They talk about whether it is inevitable that there is a doppelganger of you, given a sufficiently large universe. Note however, that some of the counter-arguments in the thread strictly relate to a *finite* universe - my earlier statement assumes an *infinite* universe.

Comment: This can be of interest: [List of references to Earth in Star Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_references_to_Earth_in_Star_Wars). It's quite safe to assume that Star Wars happen during human space colonization era, but "A long time ago" before era of peace.

Comment: "My own thought is that placing the story in the distant past gives a more mythic feel." Yes, and placing a story *with many futuristic elements* in the distant past communicates a cyclical view of time (a characteristic of Eastern religious worldviews). In a cyclical view of time, "relative to what" hardly matters.

Answer (score 35):

I don't know if this is canonical, but I believe the answer is that the setting is "a long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away" relative to *any* given viewer regardless of their position in the space-time continuum.  Presenting this up-front tells the viewer that they should put aside any pre-conceptions of how the galaxy, its politics, technology, or life-forms should be constructed.  It entirely separates the fantasy world from reality, to provide a deeper immersion into the story.

Comment: I like it.  I don't think I believe it, but I like it.

Comment: It's basically "Once upon a time..." - except in space!

Answer (score 5):

Authors and researchers may speculate, but I doubt you'd find a canonical answer from George. From what I remember of George's comments (DVD commentaries, documentaries, etc.), he's inclined to want to include as many "mythological motifs" as possible. Consider also the somewhat whimsical initial conception of *Star Wars,* which apparently included dialogue references to *The Lord of the Rings* and was entitled *Adventures of Luke Starkiller, As Taken From the Journal of the Whills, Saga 1: The Star Wars.* As such, Star Wars is framed in many ways as mythology or a fairy tale, for which the deliberately non-specific "long ago and far away" setting is customary.

So until G.L. tells us, which is probably never, the flippant and yet also accurate answer to your question is "probably somewhere in this universe (since there are humans), during the same time period as Snow White and Ali Baba."

Answer (score 4):

I just found a interesting article that may answer the *when* part : [A Chart That Explains How Long Ago Star Wars Actually Took Place](https://io9.com/5890342/a-chart-that-explains-how-long-ago-star-wars-actually-took-place) on io9. **It place the Battle of Yavin (*Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope*) in 1804 of ours time.**

It bases is math on *[Into the Great Unknown](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Into_the_Great_Unknown)* from *Dark Horse's [Star Wars Tales #19](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Tales_19)*. Here form [Star Wars Tales Wookieepedia article](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Tales)

> Issue #1 to Issue #20 were edited by Peet Janes (Issues 1 and 2) and Dave Land (Issues 3-20) and **were labeled Infinities, placing them outside the canon** (though this is not to say that the events depicted are permanently outside of the official continuity, just that they should not be considered canon unless or until they are endorsed by a canon source)

So, It's not really canon, but its the best we could find.

Comment: The Star Wars galaxy isn't our Galaxy.  If Han and Chewie could cross galaxies, I'm willing to bet they could play fast & loose, temporally.  The i09 article is baseless, since the *Falcon* took a step to the left, a hop to the right, and did the time warp again.

Comment: @Jeff It's just a **jump** to the left.

Comment: @RossPresser And then a *step* to the right.

Answer (score 3):

This is addressed by Pablo Hidalgo in [*Star Wars Insider #69*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_69). In short, there's no specific time or place.

> **Q. What is the setting for Star Wars movies? I know it's *"A long time ago"*, but what year exactly?**
>
> **PH:** There is **no specific date assigned to the events of the Star Wars movies** and there will likely never be. That famous introductory line is supposed to inform audiences that the following two-hours-and-change are pure escapist fantasy, and the rules and preconceptions of the dreary world do not apply. **Asking how long "a long time ago" is akin to asking "once upon *what* time?" at the start of a fairy tale**

Answer (score 1):

The timeline on the star wars wiki states that the creation of its Galaxy was 13 billion years prior to the Battle of Yavin (during episodes 4-5-6). Our own Galaxy is 13.2 billion years old and the universe Is 13.8 billion years old. If the galaxies were in fact created at relatively the same point, .6 billion years after the Big Bang. Than we can assume that the original trilogy took place 200 million years ago, but say the galaxies were formed at different points, say the star wars Galaxy was formed around 799700 years after the Big Bang, 199700 years after ours, than Star Wars: into the great unknown could be considered true in the fact that the battle of Yavin occurred around 1804. Although that doesn't seem too "a long time ago". I prefer the former of BOY taking place 200 million years ago.

Comment: The current universe is about 13.8 billion years old. _Star Wars_ could conceivably take place during a previous universe, one otherwise entirely unknown to us now. That would place the Battle of Yavin has having taken place at least about 14 billion years ago, which is a _seriously_ long time ago.

Comment: You need to add some zeroes. .6 billion years is 600,000,000 years.