# Do we really know the scale of things in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

I'm asking about Star Wars because it claims to take place in our universe, but disconnected from us in space and time (a long time ago, in a galaxy far far away).

Even though the Star Wars universe has "humans", do we really know the scale of everything in the Star Wars universe to be the same as in the real world? Maybe everything in Star Wars is 10% the size, or 100%, or 10X bigger; or smaller.

The wikia page for the [Imperial Standard Meter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_standard_meter) presumes that an Imperial Standard Meter is the same as a meter. This is not convincing.

Is there anything in canon, which really relates the scale of things in Star Wars to the real world? For example, knowing the speed on light in Imperial Standard units would do the job (presuming that we assume that the relationship between Imperial time units and SI time units is known).

Comment: My question is why would you presume they were NOT the same? What particular benefit would you get from assuming things were bigger or smaller than they appeared to be from the films. They are measured in meters, feet, yards, miles or lightyears, why would they be using a measure different from the ones we use if the writers want us to be able to identify with them without having to constantly remeasure things in our head?

Comment: @Thaddeus:   why would you assume they ARE the same?  Not having a reason to presume they aren't the same isn't a reason to presume they *are* the same.

Comment: But seeing how HUMANS are designing the series, humans are writing the series, humans have to build the sets, design the products, Humans even star in the series. The canon publications list everything in human measurements, OUR measurement systems. Why would you ASSUME THEY WOULD BE DIFFERENT? It's a question that answers it self because the simplest answer is most likely to be right. They would use the same measurement systems because we created them. If they were aliens, written BY aliens, THAT might make them potentially different.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no canon source...I've read a lot of books and other SW-related 'research' and have never seen it explicitly compare a SW-related unit to our world. There's just no point, since the units they use appear to be 'standard' and similar to ours to make it easy to understand (Galactic Coordinated Time, Standard meter, Galactic Basic)

Comment: I'd vote for everything in the Star Wars universe being smaller.  That might explain the lack of handrails everywhere; falls aren't such a big deal when terminal velocity is low because of air resistance.  Much easier to have flying cars and jet packs, too.

Comment: I'm not convinced it would help, however if you're interested @ThePopMachine, there is a light year in the Star Wars galaxy. All depends what a 'year' is however! http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Light-year

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I thought you might like to reconsider your acceptance now that you have a canonical answer :-)

Comment: @Valorum:   I'm not sure why that answer is particularly more canon.   Unless you question whether  E.T. is really from Brodo Asogi?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Because the Brodo Asagi are not (canonically) the same aliens as the ones seen in E.T. - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/are-e-t-and-star-wars-in-the-same-universe/6558#6558

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### The canon answer is yes.

Per the (fully Disney canon) [Star Wars Made Easy](https://www.dk.com/us/features/us/star-wars-made-easy/) factbook, the "*humans*" we see in the Star Wars universe are anatomically identical to Earth-humans. This obviously includes their size and scale.

> **ARE THE HUMANS THERE "US"?**
>
> *You mean, did they come from Earth and have our history? No, they're
>   in a galaxy far, far away—I thought we covered this! **These humans are
>   not related to us at all, though they are anatomically identical,** 
>   which probably made casting the movies a lot easier.*

Comment: In theory, couldn't they be anatomically identical but sized on a different scale? *"He is exactly like you in every way... except 1/8th your size"*

Comment: @Skooba - Judge me by my size, do you? And he's 4 inches tall...

Comment: Nice find there!!

Answer (score 28):

See [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6555/3025) and [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6558/3025).

Star Wars and E.T. are in the same universe. Members of E.T.'s species appear in the Senate chamber in Star Wars Episode I.

The humans that appear in E.T. are at least roughly the same size, relative to E.T., that the Star Wars humans are relative to the folks from Brodo Asogi in Star Wars.

(The idea of Star Wars and E.T. being in the same universe almost certainly started as a joke, but according to the linked answer, Spielberg and Lucas have put enough canon information in both universes to confirm it.)

Conclusion: Earth humans and Star Wars humans are close to the same size.

This assumes, of course, that E.T. takes place in our universe; we see more than enough information in the movie to confirm that that's the intention. It's conceivable, I suppose, that E.T. takes place in a parallel universe with a different scale, but that's not particularly plausible.

**EDIT :**

There are also physical problems with having human-shaped creatures of significantly different sizes. We've seen Star Wars humans walking around on a number of different planets, and they always appear to be moving normally. A human-shaped creature that's say, 10 meters tall would move very differently, assuming he could even support his own weight. Lower gravity could partly solve that, but then such creatures would have to move more slowly, and we'd have to assume that the movies are shown with a different time scale. Similar considerations apply for smaller human-like creatures. And we'd have to assume that the Galaxy Far Far Away is full of planets that appear Earth-like, but that *consistently* have substantially different surface gravities *and* breathable atmospheres.

(Personally, I like the idea that the "humans" in Star Wars are not human at all, that they're some random alien species that happens to dominate the galaxy, and they're *portrayed* by human actors in the movies for the sake of storytelling. But the E.T./Brodo Asogi connection probably contradicts that idea.)

Comment: If Star Wars and E.T. are the same Universe, how is it that Star Wars is a *movie franchise* in the E.T. Universe?  (Elliot plays with a Boba Fett action-figure, and has Star Wars-themed pajamas and blankets!)

Comment: @Channel72 Just because something was thought of in science fiction on Earth, doesn't mean it *hasn't* happened somewhere, "a long time ago, in a galaxy far away".

Comment: @Channel72 - Writers love doing stuff like this. For another example, Futurama and the Simpsons have crossed over into each others' stories, but they are [apparently also fictional](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/19674/33) to each other.

Comment: See, it is answerable!   Great one!

Comment: I did not think to look at it this way. Brilliant!

Comment: @Channel72 - maybe E.T. brought the idea of Star Wars to earth!

Comment: @Channel72 - Because star wars 4-6 are actually a documentary about what happened a long long time ago in a galaxy far far away... 1-3 are anti Nemodian propaganda designed to color our trade relations with them.

Comment: George Lucas is a Force user and saw the whole thing. And decided he could use it to sell toys.

Comment: We should bear in mind that the events in the Star Wars movies, and also in Phantom Menace, etc, happened "a long time ago". If the time scale is sufficient for evolution to have occurred, the ET-creatures may have evolved to, um, look exactly the same but be substantially larger or smaller in scale. Yeah, that's the ticket.

Comment: @JonKiparsky: Sure, it was [a long time ago](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12250/3025) -- but unless the laws of physics were different, it's not likely that the human-like creatures we saw on screen could have been much larger or smaller than us.

Comment: @KeithThompson - sorry, I thought it was clear that I was jumping on the "stupid answers to a stupid question" bandwagon. Oh, look, here's another: why would we assume that the laws of physics are similar, given the manifest and well-catalogued failures of physics in the three Star Wars movies, and also the various desperate attempts to drag the story out into eternity?

Comment: This is not a serious attempt to answer the question, and the reasoning is obviously not canon. While the aliens do look identical to E.T., Han Solo looks identical to Harrison Ford. Luke Skywalker looks like a European-descended American. That doesn't mean any of those things exist in the Star Wars galaxy.

Comment: @ConradBennishJr: See [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6558/3025), which I linked to in mine. The connection between the Star Wars and E.T. universes is clearly (IMHO) a joke, but that doesn't mean it's not canon. See also the physical arguments in my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson in that case, since Lucas and Spielberg purposely put reliefs of R2D2 and C3PO in Indiana Jones (again as a joke), Indiana Jones is Star Wars canon? Your physical arguments are definitely valid (though they don't cover small differences). I feel your answer would work better if it focused on them.

Comment: @ConradBennishJr: Feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson I did, but have retracted it as valorum’s answers it quite well using a proper canon source which disproves the argument I put forward in mine.